# Android PDF reader for huge files

Tags: android, pdf

Basically I'm searching for an alternative to Google PDF Viewer that actually is the only capable of handling files of 15.000 pages of jpgs and 4-5 GB of size.

The only problem with the google one is that it doesn't even handle the bookmarks, don't have option on visualizing modes and doesn't have a go to page!

I'm open to other options even paid ones - note: Pay once not subscription models.

I don't need any edits.. just a powerful optimized reader with bookmarks and minor other functions and performance tweaking..

But it should be a program written without any extra permissions, no ads, no malware, adware or anything bad in mind, a program written by a person who intends to even earn money from it but once it is sold the program is your and just works.

Answer (score 2):

Due to not having a file so large to test, I cannot affirm this will work. However you should look into PDF Reader from pspdfkit. Excellent app that handled anything I threw at it, with bookmarking support and minimal permissions.

Comment: I'm checking it however there's a very stupid function that I already hate. It has to copy the file inside it's folder from the SD card. What's the point of it and how to remove this ? Acrobat Reader do the same and is very very stupid and unnecessary.

Comment: I don't have that issue. I can click on a pdf file using any file manager and it will display it in PDF viewer. Check if you have granted PDF Viewer the storage permission in App Settings.

Comment: It has the storage permission. You don't see it because probably you are just opening files that are very small. So it copy the files from sd to internal storage fastly and you don't see the progress dialog, but it does it. Android 6 here.

Comment: I'm not the developer of the app, and I cannot verify how it works. Can you try to go in to the app, and choosing the SD card option to access the file, rather than clicking on file through a file explorer. It should ask for an additional permission to access SD card, and should display from disk, versus copying to internal storage.